# Format italic/bold with XSLT to HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a XML Document like this:

```
<bibliography>
    <element1>
        <text>
            Some text and <italic>italic Text</italic> and <bold>bold text</bold>
        </text>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <text>
            Some text and <italic>italic Text</italic> and <bold>bold text</bold>
        </text>
    </element2>
</bibliography>
```

This XSL works but does not format `<italic>` or `<bold>` tags.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Bibliographie</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                .entry {
                    font-family: Georgia
                }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/bibliography/*">
    <p>
        <div class="entry{@type}">
    [<xsl:number count="*"/>]
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

What do I have to add to let it format the `<italic>` and `<bold>` tags right for HTML?
I tried it with XSL-FO but it seems that I can't export the objects to HTML, just to PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've asked a similar question about outputting xsl-fo. The principal is the same for HTML, but just output HTML tags instead of xsl-fo ones.

The main issue why you XSLT doesn't work is because you haven't got templates matching either **bold** or **italic**

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="bibliography">
        <html>
           <head>
               <title>Bibliographie</title>
               <style type="text/css">
               .entry {
                   font-family: Georgia
               }
           </style>
           </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bibliography/*">
       <div class="entry{@type}">
          [<xsl:number count="*"/>]
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bibliography/*/*" priority="0">
       <p>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="italic">
        <span style="font-style:italic;">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </span>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not the use of "priority" on one of the templates

```
 <xsl:template match="bibliography/*/*" priority="0">
```

This acts as a sort-of "catch-all" template for matching elements where you don't have specific templates. The priority is needed to ensure it doesn't get applied ahead of the templates matching "italic" and "bold" for example. This was, if you have other elements you want to format in a specific way, such as "author", just add a specific template for them.

Comment: Somehow this is not working for me. This is my XML file: [link](http://pastebin.com/LLG1RC2w) and my XSLT from you: [link](http://pastebin.com/ksJ847rb) It seems that its generating the HTML right, but the formatting is horrible. This is the output in my browser (firefox): [link](http://s14.directupload.net/images/140710/gprtr6ol.png)

Comment: I forgot to say that there are several elements which can contain `<italic` or `<bold>` tags. Sorry for this. What do I have to change, to give out every element in one paragraph containing all elements below with the `<italic` or `<bold>` tags?

Comment: Because of the use of `xsl:apply-templates` it should still pick up **italic** and **bold**. However, I have made an edit to my question to allow a bit more flexibility of what is output. I also noticed I had set it to output method "xml" and not "html".